# AWS EKS containers cant access external hosts

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Im having trouble accessing external hosts from within my containers running in an EKS kubernetes cluster. when I start a container with "host" networking things are working. any ideas?

Comment: What’s your network overlay?

Comment: Can you please clarify on how exactly do you start containers (run Pods you mean?) with 'host' networking. Doesn't sound to me like a thing you could do directly on EKS /Kubernetes.